# java SWING использование MVC

Tags: java, mvc, swing

Опираясь на патерн MVC то для элемента JTable моделью является интерфейс TableModel. 
**Что тогда (какие классы или интерфейсы) есть преставлением и контролером?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представлением является сам `JTable`. В качестве контроллеров выступают "слушатели" событий.

Подробнее об этом можно почитать [на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793888/correct-model-view-controller-pattern-in-java-swing).

**Обновление**

Через экземпляр `JTable` можно сделать довольно многое. Если не годятся стандартные методы, делайте свой `Renderer`.

**Обновление 2**

`Renderer` это более детальное управление отрисовкой (читайте внешним видом) `JTable`. То, что  невозможно реализовать стандартными средствами `JTable` (используя стандартный `Renderer` по умолчанию) реализуется средствами собственного `Renderer`-а.

**Обновление 3**

Вот [пример](http://www.sbp-program.ru/java/sbp-jtable-renderer.htm) `Renderer`-а столбцов с объяснениями. Вот [пример](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/implementsTableCellRenderer.htm) `Renderer`-а ячеек.

Comment: но через экземпляр JTable нельзя изменить, например, цвет линий столбцов!!! Наверно нужно использовать что то другое ?

Comment: я так понимаю, что JTable - для общих настроек! Rendere поможет управлять, например, цветом линий колонок ??

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @Streletz, можно ссылку на хороший пример???

Comment: @Vitaliy, ссылки на примеры добавил в ответ.

Comment: @Streletz, спасибо! Буду разбираться!!!

Answer (score 3):

Model - это данные которые будут отображаться в JTable, View - это то что будет формировать UI(в данном случае JTable и аттрибуты которые устанавливают кол-во колонок и т.д.), Controller - отвечает за взаимодействие с пользователем через UI. В Вашем случае это может быть форма выборки из БД либо же кнопки для скрытия отдельных колонок.

Comment: Кнопки и прочие GUI элементы имеют свои модели, контроллеры и представления. Это полностью самостоятельные элементы управления.

Comment: Никто не говорил что не имеют, просто вопрос о паттерне MVC  - а  это условности для разделения кода на три составляющие 
1. Данные - которые нужно предоставить; 
2. Визуальная часть - для отображения данных; 
3. Контроллер для взаимодействия с пользователем. 
Если разбирать элемент JTable отдельно то Вы правы.

Comment: Вопрос не просто о паттерне MVC. Речь идёт об MVC в контексте его конкретной реализации. Здесь контроллерами являются именно классы "слушатели" событий. Кнопки, "флажки" и т.д. это визуальная часть, которая может быть изменена, но логика обработки кликов и т.д. (взаимодействие с пользователем) останется той же самой независимо от того управляется ли видимость столбцов кнопкой или "флажком". При условии следования архитектуре паттерна.